# How to merge two CNN deep learning model using weighted sum and weighted product in Keras?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, cnn, convolutional-neural-network

I am using Keras to create a deep learning model and I want to merge two CNNs by using weighted sum or weighted product.

How can I merge two CNNs using weighted sum and weighted product?

Comment: here a simple way to operate a learnable weighted average: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62595660/weighted-average-custom-layer-weights-dont-change-in-tensorflow-2-2-0/62595957#62595957

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most elegant way is to [write a layer](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/) that does this. For example for the case of the weighted sum:

```py
class WeightedSum(Layer):

    def __init__(self, a, **kwargs):
        self.a = a  # "weight" of the weighted sum
        super(WeightedSum, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, model_outputs):
        return self.a * model_outputs[0] + (1 - self.a) * model_outputs[1]

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0]
```

Suppose you have two models `model1` and `model2` with outputs `out1` and `out2` respectively. This layer simply performs the operation:

$$
out = a \cdot out_1 + (1-a) \cdot out_2
$$

You can compute a weighted product the same way, just change the `call` method.

---

#### Example

```py
from keras.layers import Layer, Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

# Define the custom layer
class WeightedSum(Layer):
    def __init__(self, a, **kwargs):
        self.a = a
        super(WeightedSum, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def call(self, model_outputs):
        return self.a * model_outputs[0] + (1 - self.a) * model_outputs[1]
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0]

# Create model1
inp1 = Input((5,))
d1 = Dense(100)(inp1)
out1 = Dense(10)(d1)
model1 = Model(inp1, out1)

# Create model2
inp2 = Input((7,))
d2 = Dense(70)(inp2)
out2 = Dense(10)(d2)
model2 = Model(inp2, out2)

# Weighed sum of the two models' outputs with a = 0.1
out = WeightedSum(0.1)([model1.output, model2.output])

# Create the merged model
model = Model(inputs=[inp1, inp2], outputs=[out])
```

Let's check the summary:

```py
>>> model.summary()
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to
==================================================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)            (None, 5)            0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_6 (InputLayer)            (None, 7)            0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)                 (None, 100)          600         input_5[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_11 (Dense)                (None, 70)           560         input_6[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_10 (Dense)                (None, 10)           1010        dense_9[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_12 (Dense)                (None, 10)           710         dense_11[0][0]
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
weighted_sum_10 (WeightedSum)   (None, 10)           0           dense_10[0][0]
                                                                 dense_12[0][0]
==================================================================================================
Total params: 2,880
Trainable params: 2,880
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Let's see if it works:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random(size=(32, 5))  # input for model1 (batch size 32)
b = np.random.random(size=(32, 7))  # input for model2 (batch size 32)

pred = model.predict([a, b])
```

Let's see if it has the right shape:

```py
>>> model.shape
(32, 10)
```

Let's see if it's the correct thing:

```
# Generate model outputs manually:
o1 = model1.predict(a)  # model1's output for array a
o2 = model2.predict(b)  # model2's output for array b

# Compute their weighted sum manually:
o = 0.1 * o1 + 0.9 * o2
```

Now if we're correct, `o` should be equal to `pred`:

```py
>>> np.array_equal(o, pred)
True
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.

Comment: Is it possible to learn "a" rather than specify it? How to write the custom layer to learn a parameter?

Comment: Yes, you can add `a` as a "trainable" weight if you initialize it as a TensorFlow variable: `self.a = tf.Variable(..., trainable=True)`. Other parameters such as the initial value and the data type can be added where I have set the 3 dots.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on my comment since I think it will be useful to anyone coming here. "a" can be trainable weight in tf.keras

```
class WeightedSum(layers.Layer):
    """A custom keras layer to learn a weighted sum of tensors"""

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(WeightedSum, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape=1):
        self.a = self.add_weight(
            name='alpha',
            shape=(),
            initializer='ones',
            dtype='float32',
            trainable=True,
        )
        super(WeightedSum, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, model_outputs):
        return self.a * model_outputs[0] + (1 - self.a) * model_outputs[1]

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0]
```

it may also be advisable to constrain alpha to be bounded [0,1].

```
constraint=tf.keras.constraints.min_max_norm(max_value=1,min_value=0)
```